# Rails Serve - Page not found - Virtual Machine [First install ever]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I installed Ruby on Rails (pain in the ass) on a VM after a lot of issues but I managed to install it. When I do "Rails S" I get the following:

`$ rails s`

```
/home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:78: warning: Insecure world writable dir /vagrant/teste2/. in PATH, mode 040777

=> Booting WEBrick

=> Rails 4.2.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000

=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options

=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server

[2015-05-23 13:10:39] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1

[2015-05-23 13:10:39] INFO  ruby 2.2.0 (2014-12-25) [x86_64-linux]

[2015-05-23 13:10:39] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=23236 port=3000
```

When I put the adress on the browser I get "Page not available ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

I tried everything :|

Comment: localhost:3000 is your local machine but you're trying to access the virtual machine's localhost right?

Comment: @Anthony Exactly, I've also already tried to specify an IP but does not work as well